# broadcast menu show/hide params - Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I would like to hide the menu bar on the selection of the menu item.When I select the contact menu, In the constructor, am emitting the close value. But I do not know where and how do I receive it.

[image]
Contact component Here

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
 import {Http} from '@angular/http';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-contact',
   templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
 })

 export class ContactComponent {

   @Output() emitClass = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

   constructor(private http: Http) {
      this.emitClass.emit(false);
   }

  }
```

Container html

```
   <div class='container-fluid'>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-12 x-content'>
            <ui-view name='page'>
                <app-search></app-search>
            </ui-view>
    </div>
    <div class='col-4 x-menu' *ngIf="menuShow" >
            <app-menu></app-menu> 
    </div>
</div>  
 </div>
```

Contact UIRef

```
export const contactState = {
  name: 'contact',
  url: '/contact',
 views: { 
   page : { 
    component: ContactComponent 
   }
 }
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

In another component where you have used the `app-contact` component, in that markup you can listen for that event. For example

```
<my-container>
   <app-contact (emitClass)="yourFunction($event)"></app-contact>
</my-container>
```

In the component of `my-container` you need to create that function and achieve event data when the `EventEmitter` will emit something

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-container',
   ...
})
export class MyContainer {

   public yourFunction(data) {

   }

}
```

Comment: thanks. it's like <div ui-view="page"> </div> and I am navigatiing through states. there is no hardcoded <app-contact>. how do I do ?